# how Animate change ColumnDefinition width in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change the width of a column by click on a button, and this change should be slow and animated.

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button >change Width Col1</Button>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Col1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Click="Button_Click">change Width Col1</Button>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
        CubicEase ease = new CubicEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.EasingFunction = ease;
        animation.Duration = duration;
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        animation.From = 1000;
        animation.To = 0;            
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Col1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth)"));

        storyboard.Begin();
  }
```

Comment: Just ask a question to how start "*"?

Comment: you can use the ActualWidth of the column

Comment: This won't work in a lot of scenarios because you are animating the MaxWidth when you need to animate Width. You can't animate the Width property with DoubleAnimation because Width is a GridLength.